# Is it faster to read from disk or generate a thumbnail on the fly?

Tags: ios, swift2

After recording a video the API allows for the generation of a thumbnail of any size. I was originally going to cache the thumbnail to disk with the video but I'm curious of it's faster to just generate on the fly instead. Anyone have any data on this?

Comment: How about cache it to disk but only do this the first time it is requested. It really wouldn't make sense to generate it each time if it isn't going to change.

Comment: The thumbnail has to be generated at least once. If it's "faster" (or if such is even relevant) to load it from disk or re-generate depends on the frequency of creating/loading the thumbnail *and* the 'cost' of [re-]generating the thumbnail from whatever source. Since the information for both are locally available..

Comment: Think of the apple photos app, is this generating them on the fly for each photo or does it have a cached little version. I'm guessing it's not loading the full resolution version for the collectionview. This makes me think that it's faster/easier to just generate it every time and not save anything to disk.

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html... Try and measure in *your particular case*. There is no generic answer for that question.